# Displaying the data from database without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

**HTML**

```
<textarea>Ask a question</textarea><button class="addquestion">POST</button>
```

After clicking the button the question is added to the database using the following Ajax, jquery and laravel. But, the question is displayed only after reloading. How can the question be added immediately after clicking the button only after storing it in database.

**Ajax And Jquery:**

```
$(document).on('click','.addquestion',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var question = $(this).prev().val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{url('/music/addquestion')}}",
        data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "question": question
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(res == true)
            {
                alert('question added!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Laravel controller**

```
public function addquestion(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->Ajax())
        {
            $question = new Question();
            $question->question=$request->question;
            if($question->save())
            {
                   echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: first append this `$(this).prev().val();` and then save it to database.

Answer (score 1):

Do so after your alert.

```
 if(res == true)
    {
       alert('question added!');
       //Add question here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).on('click','.addquestion',function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var question = $(this).prev().val();
       // you can show the question by `question var` from here by using 
       // $('selecter').html(question); or if appending to any input type field
       //$('selecter').val(question); or 
       //you can append it when you got success response
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "{{url('/music/addquestion')}}",
            data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "question": question
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(res == true)
                {
                    alert('question added!');
                   // $('selecter').html(question); or 
                  //$('selecter').val(question); 


                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the div

```
<textarea>Ask a question...</textarea><button class="addquestion">POST</button>
<div id="question"></div>
```

json encode the variable:

```
echo json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE,'question'=>$request->question));die;
```

Display:

```
success: function (data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(response.status == true)
            {
                var question=response.question;
                $('#question').append(question);                
            }
```